# Is there any safe way to delete and reconfigure a firebase app at running time

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, firebase

I need to send my application analytics on two firebase project depending upon the situations. so I need to delete previous app that has been configured at first runtime, to configure new one.

I have created instances of FirebaseOptions to configure at different situations

```
 if summit {
    let summitFireBaseConfigFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "summit-google-service", ofType: "plist")
    let firOptions = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: summitFireBaseConfigFile!)
    FirebaseApp.configure(options: firOptions)
    }
    else {
    let goFireBaseConfigFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "go-google-service", ofType: "plist")
    let firOptions = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: goFireBaseConfigFile!)
    FirebaseApp.configure(options: firOptions)
    }
```

app gets crashed whenever i tried to reconfigure Firebase app.
so i need to delete already initialise app then only reconfigure new one`

**Solution**
I Have solved it by deleting the firstly initialised Firebase App then configured new one.

```
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info-summit-tagatay", ofType: "plist")
        guard let fOptions = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: filePath!)
            else
        {
            assert(false, "Couldn't load config file")
            return
        }
        if (FirebaseApp.app() != nil){
            FirebaseApp.app()?.delete({response in
                FirebaseApp.configure(options: fOptions)

            })
        }else {
            FirebaseApp.configure(options: fOptions)
        }
```

Comment: If you mean "while running" (which is what it seems you want - your code is not complete and the text is not clear....), then you will have issues with this as the FB apps have different features (and perhaps users) - so I believe this won't be possible (changing the app after initialization).  If that is not what you are asking, then show error codes and/or "gets crashed" information that someone can help you with.  Show where 'summit' is being stored/determined, etc......  DETAILS are important to getting help!

Comment: issue was resolved

Comment: Can you please explain how you resolved it @AsHwinShaKya ??

Comment: Yes, how did you solve it?